# I want to make all images look inline

Tags: reactjs

[This is what I am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TU7Zl.png)

**This is the code in which I want to make these images all aligned in same line. This is the react code in which I am taking the image and using it.  But after making the div display inline it is still not working.**

```
function MidHeader(){
    return (
        <div>
                <div>
                    <img
                        src={Mobile}
                        width="70"
                        height="70"                     
                        alt="Mobile logo"
                      />
                      <p>Mobile</p>
                    <img
                        src={Electronic}
                        width="70"
                        height="70" 
                        display = "inline"              
                        alt="Electronic logo"
                      />
                      <p>Electronic</p>
                </div>
        </div>
        )

}
```

Comment: This is caused by <p> tag. If you remove <p> tag, then it will work.

Comment: ' making the div display inline' --> you should check whether you have set the width 100%. Or you can try the answer below as I suggest. Using the ```flex```. Of course, if you have a jsfiddle or codepen link, it is definitely better as we can 'see' what problem you face

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `flex` can tackle the problem.

```
<div className='wrapper'>
    <img
        src={Mobile}
        width="70"
        height="70"                     
        alt="Mobile logo"
        />
        <p>Mobile</p>
        //more code
</div>
```

```
//css file 

.wrapper{
   display: flex; 
   width: 100%; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need explanation for images, then You can refer bellow code.

```
function MidHeader(){
    return (
        <div style={{display:'inline'}}>
                <div style={{display:'block'}}>
                    <img
                        src={Mobile}
                        width="70"
                        height="70"                     
                        alt="Mobile logo"
                      />
                      <p>Mobile</p>
                 </div>
                 <div style={{display:'block'}}>
                    <img
                        src={Electronic}
                        width="70"
                        height="70" 
                        display = "inline"              
                        alt="Electronic logo"
                      />
                      <p>Electronic</p>
                </div>
        </div>
        )

}
```